# format the String to form a new String from it

Tags: java

I receive a String in this format `TEST [52.5, 77.5]`

With this above string received i want to form two elements as shown below

```
TEST 52.5

TEST 77.5
```

I have tried as shown below , but was not getting the output i desired .

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String string = "TEST [52.5, 77.5]";
        String strModf = string.replaceAll("\\[", " ");
        String newStr = strModf.replaceAll("\\]", " ");

        // Used StringBuffer here but not able to succeed .

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
String str = "TEST [52.5, 77.5]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\s*\\[(.*)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.find()) {
    String first = m.group(1);
    String[] others = m.group(2).split("\\s*,\\s*");

    for (String other : others)
        System.out.println(first + " " + other);
}
```

```
TEST 52.5
TEST 77.5
```

Comment: I have took up the string HFC Jan 18 2014 [16.0, 18.0, 21.0, 23.0, 24.5] , and its not working .

Comment: @PreethiJain If you have a more complicated example could you put that in the question?

Comment: @arshajii , this is a sample of my String  HFC Jan 18 2014 [16.0, 18.0, 21.0, 23.0, 24.5]

Answer (score 2):

Since numbers inside square brackets might vary, I would suggest slightly different approach for extensibility reason:

```
String s = "TEST [52.5, 77.5, 86.5]";
String slist = s.replaceAll("^.*?\\[\\s*([^\\]]+)\\s*\\]", "$1");
String fword = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(' ')+1);
for (String t : slist.split(",\\s*"))
    System.out.println(fword + t);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
TEST 52.5
TEST 77.5
TEST 86.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of:

```
    String string = "TEST [52.5, 77.5]";
    String strFirst = string.replaceFirst("\\[", "").replaceFirst(",.*", "");
    String strSecond = string.replaceFirst("\\[.*,\\s+", "").replaceFirst("\\]", "");
    System.out.println(strFirst);
    System.out.println(strSecond);
```

outputs

```
TEST 52.5
TEST 77.5
```

From [regex apidoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> .        Any character (may or may not match line terminators)
>   X*     X, zero or more times 
>   \s     A whitespace character: \p{IsWhite_Space}
>   X+      X, one or more times

Comment: thanks for the answer , this looks good , but i can have more number of elements inside the square brackets .

Comment: you are welcome. you should have noted that in question though.

Answer (score 0):

If you'r not a regexp fan you can do some thing like this (hugly ? no!!!) :

`String str = "TEST [75.1, 7.52]";`

`String root = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('['));`

`String elements = str.substring(str.indexOf('[')+1, str.indexOf(']'));`

`String[] parts = elements.split(",");`

`String elem1 = root+ " " + parts[0];`

`String elem2 = root+ " " + part[1];`

A bit more verbose i know.

Comment: bte `String#split` also uses regex

Comment: yes but realy more simple to understand than complex paterns (i'm not a very smart coder in fact ... )